# How to use string arguments in layout.xml

Tags: android, string, layout

We use getString(R.string.test,**1**) where **1** is argument in

```
<string name=test>Hello %1$d</string>
```

This works in java, but i want to use the same in **android:text** for textviews in layout.xml.
But when I use:
`@string/test` it displays `Hello %1$d` or `@string/test,0` then gives error( not the expected string). Is there a way to provide argument for string in layout.xml?

Comment: there is no way to do it in layout xml unfortunately.

Comment: That is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it programmatically like below.

```
mTextView.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.test), 1));
```

Comment: i did'nt knew that it was impossible to do via layout.xml